# Formulário desarrumou depois de adicionar um ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

eu tinha um formulário pronto no meu VS, Após ele estiver pronto, me dei conta que eu precisaria adicionar um ScrollBar.
Pesquisar e vi que para solucionar o meu problema era so adicionar um ScrollViewer.
Quando eu Adiciono, o meu formulário fica tudo fora de ordem, uma label de um lado e um textbox de outro. Porque???

Me ajudem =(

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfSistemaDinamCorp.Telas.CadastroEmpresa"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="Cadastro de Empresa" Height="1081" Width="1400" WindowState="Maximized" UseLayoutRounding="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Grid Margin="0,0,18,21" UseLayoutRounding="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,52" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="CADASTRO DE EMPRESA" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="302" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="528,0,544,0"/>
    <Label Content="Código:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Content="CNPJ / CPF:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Content="Razão Social / Nome:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,34,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,65,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="559" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Content="Nome Fantasia:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"/>
    <Label Content="CEP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,152,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,152,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158"/>
    <Label Content="Código IBGE:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,184,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,183,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158"/>
    <Label Content="Tipo de Logradouro:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,215,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,215,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158"/>
    <Label Content="Inscrição Estadual:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,246,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Inscrição Municipal:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,278,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="RNTRC:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,309,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,246,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,278,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,309,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/>
    <Label Content="Apelido:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="474,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="528,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"/>
    <Label Content="Site:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="819,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="851,121,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244"/>
    <Label Content="Município:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,184,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="425,183,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>
    <Label Content="Bairro:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="693,184,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="742,183,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
    <Label Content="Estado (UF):" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="967,183,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1045,183,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
    <Label Content="Logradouro:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,215,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Número:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="681,215,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Complemento:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="906,216,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="425,216,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="742,216,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="999,216,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
    <Label Content="Cód. Serv.:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,246,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Cód. Ativ.:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="675,246,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Regime Trib.:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,278,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Tipo de Empresa:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,309,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="474,247,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="742,247,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="353"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="475,278,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="620"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="475,309,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="620"/>
    <Label Content="CNAE - Classificação Nacional de Atividades Econômicas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,336,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="Código:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,362,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Descrição:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="320,362,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,362,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="389,362,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="605"/>
    <Button Content="Adicionar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1006,362,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90 "/>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,393,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="962" Height="60"/>
    <Label Content="Descrição da Atividade:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-2,456,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,456,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="965"/>
    <Label Content="Contatos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,483,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="E-mail:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,509,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,510,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350"/>
    <Label Content="Observação:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="517,509,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="597,510,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397"/>
    <Button Content="Adicionar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1006,510,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,541,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="965" Height="60"/>
    <Label Content="Prefixo (99):" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,606,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Telefone:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,606,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Observação:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="580,606,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,607,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="296,607,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="660,607,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1006,606,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,638,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="965" Height="58"/>
    <Button Content="Salvar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,731,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
    </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de utilizar um *StackPanel* e tentar posicionar os *Label* e *TextBox* através do uso de *Margin* e *Alignment*, construa o seu formulário usando uma *Grid*.

Um formulário, na sua forma mais simples, não é mais do que uma lista, onde cada linha é um par de elementos *Label* -> *TextBox*

Por isso use uma *Grid* com duas colunas para definir o formulário.
Na primeira coluna coloque os *Label* e na segunda os *TextBox*.
Cada uma das linhas será então um conjunto *Label* -> *TextBox*.

Assim, só será necessário definir a altura da linha e a largura da coluna da *Grid* para que tudo fique alinhado.

Essa *Grid* é colocada dentro da *ScrollView*:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
   <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" >
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           .....
           .....
           // Tantas quanto o número de pares *Label* -> *TextBox*
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      //Introduza aqui o Label indicado Grid.Column="0" e Grid.Row="0"
      //depois o TextBox indicado Grid.Column="1" e Grid.Row="0"
      //e assim sucessivamente, aumentando o valor de Grid.Row em cada par Label -> TextBox
   </Grid>        
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Você consegue me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso? Pq antes de eu colocar esse StackPanel, ele estava tudo ok. E eu coloquei ele mesmo só para poder ter um Scroll pq meu formulario ficou grande demais...

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez Ramaral. Vc é um gênio! xD